# Renew SSL root CA cert - client programs in the wild need update?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509

Here is my situation:

- I have a client application that I'm going to distribute - we'll call it MyClient.
- MyClient does some SSL communication with one of our servers.
- MyClient has the root CA embedded in it, so it can do proper verification of the server certificate.

Now, suppose some years go by, the root CA expires, and is renewed.

Does that mean I need to patch MyClient in the wild?

In other words, will a change to the validity dates on the certificate cause it to no longer match the baked-in root CA in MyClient?

**Addendum:** Suppose I write my client to not validate the date of the cert (but everything else). Then, when the root CA expires and is re-issued, do I still need to patch? Will other parts that play into the validation change, other than the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client is ensuring an SSL server certificate is issued by a particular root CA and that root CA is included in the client then yes, you will need to patch your client to replace the root CA certificate.

There are few good ways of doing this. What tends to happen is that root CA certificates are very long lived and use shorter lived intermediate CAs to issue SSL certificates but it sounds like this is not the case here.

Looking on the bright side, I do not know what algorithms were used with the old root CA certificate but, hopefully, The new root CA certificate will hopefully use a larger key (2048-bit RSA rather than 1024-bit or 512-bit) and a better hashing algorithm (SHA1 or better rather than MD5) so it may be a good opportunity to increase security.

Comment: I should add: if I set my client to not verify dates, will I be able to leave it un-patched, even if the root CA cert is updated? In other words, are the valid dates the only things that will change with a re-issue, or does the whole thing change?

Comment: If you do not validate the date then you will not need to issue a new certificate and not need to patch your clients. Some products that use digital certificates for perpetual licensing do this.

Comment: Just to be clear: The root CA is outside of my authority in this case. It *will* expire, and it *will* be re-issued. But if my client does not validate dates, will it still need to be patched?

Comment: If you will need to support certificates used by the new CA, you will need to patch your client to accept certificates from both CAs. However, you will not need to reissue it for the expiry if you do not check the dates. You may want also  to confirm the certificate library you are using supports an expired root CA. Many of them have options to ignore the validity periods on end certificates but may or may not ignore dates on the root certificate.